# Why I can´t replace Android Google Drive Api with REST API Java?

Tags: android-studio, google-drive-api, dependencies, google-drive-android-api

I have following dependecy to [Android Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). Because this API will be shut down, I have to move that to [JAVA REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0'
```

But I can´t do it, because each time I add new dependency, I got error.

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add following lines to gradle.properties.

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableD8.desugaring=false
```

With this build works, but Android Studio warns me not to do it.

```
The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
```

EDIT:
**[I followed this tutorial and it works without disabling D8.](https://ammar.lanui.online/integrate-google-drive-rest-api-on-android-app-bc4ddbd90820)**

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```